# Getting separated meshes to use the same armature (clothes and hair moving with body ex)

Tags: modeling, objects, rigging, armature, bones

When I made my character model I made it as 3 seperate objectes: one for body one for clothes and one for hair. I then joined these objects using the 'ctrl + j' command. 
[image: regular]

I have created armature but the manipulating the armature only moves body + objects that are connected with the body(ears).

[image]

I'm not sure if I should somehow separate these objects again and give them their own armature (seems kind of labor intensive)

Or if there is a way to 'merge' the meshes so they are all connected and can move along with the poses.
If anyone has any guidance or can point me in the right direction it is greatly appreciated. The similar questions I have found differ in the fact that the user is using separate objects while I am using one.

Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+J then Ctrl+P and automatic weights should work here (eventually, you can separate dress and hair after that). But the rig won't be 'perfect' : the hair won't move with the head only (it will be influenced by the legs too, for instance) and the body may overlap the dress. So you need to work on the weight paint and (maybe) need to add some more geometry to the dress to allow it to bend properly with the bones movements

Answer (score 1):

I would parent the object to the a bone that makes sense and then just make sure that bone is has full influence over it.

Comment: Hi , thanks for responding. Do you mean selecting a bone and putting its parent as the object. Or somehow making the object's parent a bone? (If so how would that be done?)

Comment: You can set the mesh to be a child of the bone and can do it with automatic weights. So you can select your mesh then shift+select your bone and hit CTRL+p and select automatic weights.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've done it but unfortunately I have the same issue.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of assistance. Cute model though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is to make sure the joined objects(i.e. after the ctrl+p step) are slightly modified such that they are connected physically via a vertex or so.

Hope I could be of help